# Mysql InnoDB Full-Text Search IN BOOLEAN MODE Sort Rows In Order of Decreasing Relevance

Tags: mysql, innodb, full-text-search, documentation

In the official documentation of [Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> Boolean full-text searches have these characteristics:
>
> - They do **not** automatically sort rows in order of decreasing relevance.

However, when running full-text searches `IN BOOLEAN MODE` (mysql v8.0.23), they are sorted by relevance in order of decreasing relevance without having to use `ORDER BY score`

```
SELECT product_category_id,
MATCH(product.barcode, product.brand_name, product.generic_name) AGAINST('paracetamol*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM product
WHERE 
MATCH(product.barcode, product.brand_name, product.generic_name) AGAINST('paracetamol*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+--------------------+
| product_category_id | score              |
+---------------------+--------------------+
|                  97 | 3.4546611309051514 |
|                  91 | 3.4546611309051514 |
|                  91 | 3.4546611309051514 |
|                  91 | 3.4546611309051514 |
|                 123 | 3.4546611309051514 |
|                 123 | 3.4546611309051514 |
|                  91 | 3.4546611309051514 |
|                  91 | 1.7273305654525757 |
|                  97 | 1.7273305654525757 |
|                  97 | 1.7273305654525757 |
```

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A guess)

There are many queries where the results are in a predictable order even without an `ORDER BY`.  However, this is often an artifact of the implementation and not a guaranteed ordering.

It used to be that `GROUP BY` automatically ordered the results as if there were a matching `ORDER BY`.  However, the existence of that as a *guarantee* hobbled the Optimizer.  With an appropriate `INDEX`, such a group by will continue to be in order.  But for other cases, the Optimizer would rather use an in-memory hash table; this essentially guarantees a somewhat random order; furthermore, it makes getting the order be an extra effort.

So, I guess, the manual is leaving the door open for some future optimization.

Rule:  If you want a particular order, specify `ORDER BY`.  If the Optimizer sees that the code can (or could) guarantee the order without doing any extra effort, it will do so.

PS, in the past, you could nullify the `GROUP BY's` implicit ordering by saying `ORDER BY NULL`.  (Kludgy?)